# Fatal error: Call to undefined function swal() - PHP

Tags: php, html

Deseo **añadir un mensaje de alerta** de la clase SweetAlert pero cuando todo está correcto y deseo mostrar el mensaje/popup me dice el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function swal()

Utilizando la página https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/ he conseguido insertar un mensaje de alerta satisfactorio "success".

```
swal("¡OK!", "¡Teléfono modificado correctamente!", "success");
```

El error lo tengo debido a que declaro antes el `swal()` antes de llamar en el HTML a la librería correspondiente, pero sin embargo, si coloco el mensaje después del `head`, entonces no funciona como deseo.

Al hacer clic en "Modificar" debe saltar el alert `swal()`.

**Código:**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    //Por defecto no mostraremos el mensaje.
    $mostrar = false;
    //Si pulsamos el botón "Modificar"...
    if(isset($_POST["modificar"])){
        $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
        //Llamamos al método "modificarCliente" y le pasamos el parámetro (teléfono).
        BD::modificarCliente($cliente, $telefono);
        //Si debemos mostrar el mensaje, la estructura es la siguiente.
        $mostrar = ["¡OK!", "¡Teléfono modificado correctamente!", "success"];
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Panel del cliente</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>     
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="menu_cliente">
            <ul id="menu_horizontal">
                <li class="nueva" id="nueva"><a class="active" href="menu_cliente.php?nueva=1#nueva">NUEVA OPINIÓN</a></li>
                <li class="ver" id="ver"><a href="menu_cliente.php?ver=1#ver">VER OPINIONES</a></li>
                <li class="eliminar" id="eliminar"><a href="menu_cliente.php?eliminar=1#eliminar">ELIMINAR OPINIÓN</a></li>
                <li class="datos_cliente" id="datos_cliente"><a href="menu_cliente.php?datos_cliente=1#datos_cliente">DATOS PERSONALES</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="cuerpo_body">
                <?php
                //Si pulsamos el link "Datos personales"...
                if(isset($_GET["datos_cliente"])){
                    //Obtengo todos los datos del cliente.
                    $objeto_cliente = BD::obtenerCliente($cliente); ?>
                <form action="menu_cliente.php?datos_cliente=1" name="miformulario" id="miformulario"  method="POST" class="form-register" onsubmit="return validar_telefono();">
                    <h2 class="form-titulo">MODIFICAR DATOS</h2>
                    <div class="contenedor-inputs">
                        <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" maxlength="9" class="input-2" value="<?php echo $objeto_cliente->getTelefono();?>" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event);">
                        <br/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Modificar" name="modificar" class="registrar"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <?php 
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            //Si hemos definido un contenido para ser mostrado, lo utilizamos...
            if ($mostrar !== false) {
                ?>
                <script language="text/javascript">
                    swal(<?= json_encode($mostrar[0]) ?>, <?= json_encode($mostrar[1]) ?>, <?= json_encode($mostrar[2]) ?>);
                </script>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Si coloco el código del botón `if(isset($_POST["modificar"])){` después de `<input type="submit" value="Modificar" name="modificar" class="registrar"/>`, me muestra el `alert()` pero no gestiona la operación realizada hasta que vuelva a pulsar el botón "Modificar". Para realizar la primera modificación, necesita dos clicks en "Modificar". **¿Cuál sería la posible solución?**

Comment: Estás mezclando código PHP y JavaScript. Estás introduciendo en un bloque de código PHP que se ejecuta en el servidor una llamada a una función JavaScript que se ejecuta en el cliente. El error de función no definida es debido a que dicha función no está disponible para PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás mezclando código PHP con código Javascript, de ahí que PHP no tenga definida dicha función.

Una forma de solucionar tu problema es posponer la llamada al final del documento de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    /* Por defecto no mostraremos el mensaje */
    $mostrar = false;
    //Si pulsamos el botón "Modificar"...
    if(!empty($_POST['telefono']) && !empty($_GET['datos_cliente'])){
        //Llamamos al método "modificarCliente" y le pasamos el parámetro (teléfono).
        BD::modificarCliente($_GET['datos_cliente'], $_POST['telefono']);
        /* Si debemos mostrar el mensaje lo marcamos así */
        $mostrar = ["¡OK!", "¡Teléfono modificado correctamente!", "success"];
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Panel del cliente</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>     
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu_cliente">
            <ul id="menu_horizontal">
                <li class="nueva" id="nueva"><a class="active" href="menu_cliente.php?nueva=1#nueva">NUEVA OPINIÓN</a></li>
                <li class="ver" id="ver"><a href="menu_cliente.php?ver=1#ver">VER OPINIONES</a></li>
                <li class="eliminar" id="eliminar"><a href="menu_cliente.php?eliminar=1#eliminar">ELIMINAR OPINIÓN</a></li>
                <li class="datos_cliente" id="datos_cliente"><a href="menu_cliente.php?datos_cliente=1#datos_cliente">DATOS PERSONALES</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="cuerpo_body">
                <?php
                //Si pulsamos el link "Datos personales"...
                if(isset($_GET["datos_cliente"])){
                    //Obtengo todos los datos del cliente.
                    $objeto_cliente = BD::obtenerCliente($cliente); ?>
                <form action="menu_cliente.php?datos_cliente=<?= url_encode($_GET["datos_cliente"]) ?>" name="miformulario" id="miformulario"  method="POST" class="form-register" onsubmit="return validar_telefono();">
                    <h2 class="form-titulo">MODIFICAR DATOS</h2>
                    <div class="contenedor-inputs">
                        <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" maxlength="9" class="input-2" value="<?php echo $objeto_cliente->getTelefono();?>" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event);">
                        <br/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Modificar" name="modificar" class="registrar"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <?php 
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
<?php
/* Si hemos definido un contenido para $mostrar, lo usamos */
if ($mostrar !== false) {
?><script>
  swal(
    <?= json_encode($mostrar[0]) ?>,
    <?= json_encode($mostrar[1]) ?>,
    <?= json_encode($mostrar[2]) ?>
  );
</script>
<?php
}
</html>
```

De esta manera se generará el código Javascript necesario para mostrar la alerta sólo si ésta se requiere. He usado [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) para convertir datos PHP en datos Javascript de manera segura.

Comment: Te acepto respuesta.